# Java Libgdx - Fire bullets

Tags: java

[image]

This is my project structure!
I am using Java Libgdx

I want to make my Man class shoot the bullets from my bullet class. To make it more clear for example the spaceship game that you shoot asteroids the bullets come from the spaceship while you move it I want the same thing.
   package com.kovach.gameobjects;

```
  import java.awt.*;

  import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter;
  import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;

public class Bullet {

int x,y;
public static TextureRegion bullet;

public static Texture texture;

public Bullet(int startX, int startY){

    x = startX;
    y = startY;
    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/texture.png"));
    texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Nearest, TextureFilter.Nearest);
    bullet = new TextureRegion(texture, 238, 5, 6, 13);
}

public void move(){

    x = x + 2;
    if (x > 700)
        visible =false;

   }



}
```

Fire method in Man class

```
   public void fire() {

    Bullet z = new Bullet((left + width), (y + height/2 ));
    bullets.add(z);

}
```

GameRenderer draw method

```
    private void drawBullets(){
    ArrayList bullets = Man.getBullets(); 
    for (int w = 0; w < bullets.size(); w++){
        Bullet m = (Bullet) bullets.get(w);

    }
}
```

Comment: Here I added the code for my bullet how do I create this bullet and make my character shoot them?

Comment: And how does you shoot() method look like in your character?

Comment: public void fire() {
     
     Bullet z = new Bullet((left + width), (y + height/2 ));
     bullets.add(z);
     
    }

Comment: You only have to look wether your fire-key is pressed (your documentation should guide you in this), and then call `Man.fire`. You may want to rotate your bullet in the right direction, but that totally is it.